# VBA not recognizing [Red] number format

Tags: excel, vba, format

I'm writing a simple code shown below, however excel doesn't seem to recgonize the [Red] number format, and is changing it to"#.##0,00" any thoughts on how to fix this? I have tried other number formats and it always seems to be the one with [Red] not being recognized.

Additionally is there a way I can shorten the code by not having to copy "Or c.NumberFormat " every time?

Thanks!

CODE BELOW

```
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Selection

    If Not c.NumberFormat = "0%" Or c.NumberFormat = "0%;(0)" Or c.NumberFormat = "0%;[Red](0%)" Then c.NumberFormat = "#.##0,00"

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You want to change the number format only if it is not one of the three formats?

Comment: Correct, so basically if its not a % give me that number format "#.##0,00", the case is I do have % which are negative and highlighted in RED, but the code is changing those % to "#.##0,00"   I fail to see why though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am almost sure your problem has nothing to do with the `Red` formatting.

In your current `If`-statement, the `Not` operator is negating only the first part, so the format `"#.##0,00"` is set to all cells that don't have the format `"0%"`

What you mean is

```
If Not (c.NumberFormat = "0%" Or c.NumberFormat = "0%;(0)" Or c.NumberFormat = "0%;[Red](0%)") Then
```

which can be changed (using simple boolean algebra, that's not VBA) to

```
If c.NumberFormat <> "0%" And c.NumberFormat <> "0%;(0)" And c.NumberFormat <> "0%;[Red](0%)" Then
```

In an `If`-statement, there is **no shortcut** like
`If c.NumberFormat = "0%" Or "0%;(0)" Or "0%;[Red](0%)"`

You can assign the format to a variable to make the If-statement shorter. This also has the advantage that the code is slightly faster as it reduces the round-trips between VBA and Excel

```
Dim nf As String
nf = c.NumberFormat
If nf <> "0%" And nf <> "0%;(0)" And nf <> "0%;[Red](0%)" Then
```

Or you could use the `Select case`-statement

```
Select Case c.NumberFormat
    Case "0%", "0%;(0)", "0%;[Red](0%)"
    Case Else
        c.NumberFormat = "#.##0,00"
End Select
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you are absolutely correct, the problem was not the RED  at all. I ended up using the SELECT CASE method, however it does have some downfalls correct? Since I first posted I included other conditions and formats and was playing around with the cases but run into errors:                                                                                                            
    Select Case c.NumberFormat
    Case "0%", "0%;(0)", "0%;[Red](0%)" then "0%;(0)"
    Case "0,00x", "0,0x", "0x"
    Case Else
        c.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"